# Excel formula to convert UTC time to Pacific Time

Tags: excel, formula, utc, eclipse-pdt

A system I am using provides UTC time in the following format. 20190802145655UT

What Excel formula could I use to convert this to a timestamp 8-2-19 7:56:55 AM? I've done a bunch of searches, but the format the time is provided in is giving me a hard time. (PDT should have been -7 hours that day.)

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=TEXT(LEFT(A1,14),"0000-00-00 00\:00\:00")-7/24
```

and format as "m-d-yy h:mm:ss AM/PM"

[image]

Comment: Ron, Thank you so much! That worked! Much appreciated.

Comment: @MarkSFO You got yourself a brilliant answer - better than the one I would have given had you told me the task as it really is. Please make sure to mark the answer as *Selected*. (There is a checkmark on the top left that you can click).

Comment: Done. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the formulas provided and neither worked for me.

I used this and it seems to work...  `=C7-7/24`
`C7` is first cell with UTC to convert

I used the following format, custom mm/dd/yyyy h:mm AM/PM

UTC converted to PST time:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This formula will convert your UT string in cell A2 to a proper date/time value.

```
=VALUE(MID(A2,19,18))
```

This could be made more complicated by searching for the opening parenthesis but I believe your format is very rigid, with the parenthesis always in 18th position. Therefore it can be hard-coded.

The formula will return a number. Format the cell with a custom format like `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` or any other format you prefer.

You can adjust the number as follows.

```
=VALUE(MID(A2,19,18))+(-7/24)
```

In this example 7 hours are being deducted from the given time. If you need more flexibility you can replace the `-7` with a cell reference.

Comment: @MarkSFO Thank you for all the fun you are giving us but Ron's is not merely the only correct answer in this thread but also a very good one. I don't know if you can still change your selection but if the system does allow it, please do mark his answer rather than mine.